# Relative Url in Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, subdirectory

I have a site on `domain.com`, I want to add sub site on `blog` subdirectory.

In `domain.com/blog/index.html` files in subdirectory, I tried to use `post-1`, `/post-1` and `./post-1` to link to a single post.

An Url expected is **`domain.com/blog/post-1`** however, the url on the link is `domain.com/post-1`.

Can .htaccess update the baseUrl of subdirectory to `domain.com/blog/`? It means all **relative url** in `blog` directory will be `domain.com/blog/[some-url-here]`.

I tried with this but it incorrect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your substitutions (2nd parameter to RewriteRule) all start with a slash ('/'). That means the base is never used.  Make them relative if you want the RewriteBase incorporated.

Comment: I removed a slash as 2nd parameter of RewriteRule, it's still not work.